# How to store record before it updated?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I use a SQL Server database. I have two tables `Inspections` and `History_Inspections`.

Before a record from the `Inspections` table is updated, I need to store it into the `History_Inspections` table.

I wanted to use a SQL Server update trigger but it fired only after the record is updated.

Any idea how can I store record from `Inspections` table in `History_Inspections` table before it updated ?

Comment: Do you really care what order the data is created? I suspect what you want is to record the values of the row before the update. You can do this in a standard trigger by looking at the values in the deleted virtual table.

Comment: @Lamak: no you don't - just read out the `Deleted` pseudo table in the trigger and you have the info needed ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger in SQL Server fires, the `Inserted` pseudo table inside the trigger contains the new values (after the `UPDATE`), and the `Deleted` pseudo table contains the **old values** (*before* the `UPDATE`).

So in your case, just read out the rows from the `Deleted` table and store those into your `History_Inspections` table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_AfterUpdateInspections
ON dbo.Inspections
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
   INSERT INTO dbo.History_Inspections(list of columns)
       SELECT (list of columns)
       FROM Deleted
```

Comment: Marc,thanks for the answer.But I am new to  SQL could you please specify what is "list of columns" is it just names of my columns in table that have to be listed like that     'Employee',
   'Name',
   'DateOfBirth'  ???

Comment: @Michael: yes, exactly - I just always recommend to **explicitly** define the list of columns, both in your `INSERT` as well as your `SELECT` statements - I try to avoid `SELECT *` and `INSERT` without a column list as much as I can